# Firebase Update with custom string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When this code executes, the result is

userId : {
    userName : userN
}

when it actually should be the params from the rest call. How can I dynamically add data to ref.update?

```
exports.addUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const userId = req.query.userId;
  const userN = req.query.userName;
  var ref = admin.database().ref("users")
  ref.update({
   userId : {
    userName : userN
  }
  });
  res.status(200).send("User added successfully");  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to specify that `userId` is a variable.

```
 exports.addUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const userId = req.query.userId;
    const userN = req.query.userName;

    const ref = admin.database().ref("users")

    ref.update({
      [userId]: {
        userName: userN,
      },
    });

    res.status(200).send("User added successfully");
  });
```

**PS**: I don't know firebase

Comment: undefined: { userName: userN }
Didn't help. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: So `userId` is `undefined`, `console.log(req.query)` to check if it's here

Comment: your first answer actually did the job. userId was undefined before